# trying to add a command to right-click for moving files

Tags: windows, cmd, registry

I'm trying to create a command in the windows context menu for the desktop (or in a folder) which moves a file or folder up one folder.  So, here's my test:

I have a folder called Parent, inside it a folder called Child, inside that a file called target.txt.  I want to be able to open Windows Explorer, right click on target.txt, select Move Up, and it'll move target.txt from Child to Parent.

I edit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ * \ shell, creating a new key called 'Move Up'.  I add a key there called 'command', and I set the Value of command to Name: (Default), Type: REG_SZ Data: cmd /c move "%1%" "..\%1" /Y/S/E/H/K/I

When I run this, I see a command window pop up quickly, which says "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

I think 'move' is an ok command to use in this context, according to this page: http://ss64.com/nt/move.html.

I have created another context menu command for backing up a folder which uses "cmd /c xcopy "%1%" "%1 Copy" /Y/S/E/H/K/I" and it works fine.

Any help?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

It is a programming question.

It a common pattern of programming questions.

To paraphrase - *Why doesn't issuing random commands work?*

**The Answer**: Because you are making the commands up and therefore noone has programmed them.

**The Solution**: READ THE DOCUMENTATION.

```
move /?
```

Comment: Serenity: this is the way this works.  An ignorant person asks a question.  A knowledgeable person provides an answer.  If all you ever do is throw some cynicism and sarcasm, and a little RTFM, you provide nothing of value.